# play framework does not want to start new app

Tags: playframework

I want check what play framework can do BUT I can't start any application. I'm doing like in tutorial, creating new project, then I'm going to directory and I try to start by typing play start

I get onlyt: 12:55:40,265 INFO  ~ Listening for HTTP on port 9000 (Waiting a first request to start) ...

The application isn't starting. I've checked diffrent ports but same result

What can it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see this message, you have to open your browser and go to http://127.0.0.1:9000.
The server will continue to execute after the first http request.

Otherwise, you can execute `play run` to run the server in the current shell.

Comment: you mean "play start" not "play run". The former is for starting the app in production mode while the latter ("run") is in dev mode.

Comment: At present he already uses `play start`. IF it doesn't work, he can try with `play run` (he will see compilation errors for example)

Comment: Yes, I see I didn't notice he was already using play start. However, "play run" does not "compile all files and start the server". Compilation doesn't happen until the first request after the server has started. In the case of "play start", compilation happens prior to the server starting. The advantage of "play run" is it allows recompiling of changed source files upon every request - and also shows errors in the browser as you mentioned. My comment was to clarify that "play run" does not compile and then start the server which is what your wording implied.